# Increasing maxlen in arules in R

Tags: r

```
library(arules)

rules <- apriori(Imp7)
inspect(rules)
rules <- apriori(Imp7,parameter = list(minlen=2, supp=0.005, conf=0.8), appearance = list(rhs=c("Status.b=D", "Status.b=G"), default="lhs"), control = list(verbose=F))
rules.sorted <- sort(rules, by="lift")
inspect(rules.sorted)
```

This is the code I am trying to run. I am kind of a beginner in R. The code line when I try to run `rules <- apriori(Imp7)` shows me: `Mining stopped (maxlen reached). Only patterns up to a length of 10 returned!`
Is there a way to change the max len?

It has 21 columns and 105 rows of data.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Setting maxtime=0 disables the time limit.

Ex.
`rules <- apriori(Imp7, parameter = list(maxtime=0))`

Answer (score 0):

Read ?"APparameter-class" about the options.

```
rules <- apriori(Imp7, parameter = list(maxlen=20))
```